# Filtering by RANK() in HAVING clause without subqueries

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm fetching group-wise maximums (the `data` CTE emulates a set of joins from actual tables):

```
with data as (
    select 'Austria' as country, 1 as id, 'red' as colour, 120 as quantity
    union all select 'Austria', 2, 'green', 96
    union all select 'Austria', 3, 'blue', 103

    union all select 'Belgium', 1, 'red', 33
    union all select 'Belgium', 2, 'green', 12
    union all select 'Belgium', 3, 'blue', 40
)
select country, colour, quantity
from (
    select country, colour, quantity,
    rank() over (partition by country order by quantity desc, id) as position
    from data
    group by country, id, colour, quantity
) subquery
where position=1;
```

**This works fine** but I'm forced to wrap the query with the `RANK()` call inside a subquery, because this alternative triggers a syntax error:

```
-- [...]
select country, colour, quantity,
rank() over (partition by country order by quantity desc, id) as position
from data
group by country, id, colour, quantity
having rank() over (partition by country order by quantity desc, id)=1;
```

> Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses.

Is there an alternative syntax to avoid this limitation or the subquery is the only sensible way?

*The ultimate goal is to integrate this code into a larger set of dynamically generated SQL expressions. If I can keep a single query I can just define the different parts (select, joined tables, where, group by, having and order by) with arrays. Otherwise I need to think a major rewrite.*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you can use top 1 with ties as below

```
select top (1) with ties country, colour, quantity,
    rank() over (partition by country order by quantity desc, id) as position
from data
--group by country, id, colour, quantity
order by rank() over (partition by country order by quantity desc, id)
```

Comment: Plus 1, but i think `group by country, id, colour, quantity` is redundant

Comment: Yes we do not require group by which is redundant

Comment: Eventhough top (1) with ties is more elegant it uses extra sort operator which is bit of costly if you have large volume of data

Comment: Thank you, this should integrate nicely with the underlying framework. The `GROUP BY` clause was a leftover of code redaction.

Answer (score 5):

If you look at performance differences i still feel subquery approach is better than the above top (1) with ties approach because of below sort operator:

Eventhough top (1) with ties is more elegant... Below are the performance differences based on Execution plan snapshot

[image]

Comment: I'm don't have experience or knowledge to judge whether a 100% sort is better or worse than two 50% sorts but I understand your overall point. Furthermore, the `TOP 1 WITH TIES` approach can be more fragile since it can easily break if I append more columns to the ORDER BY clause.

Comment: If you see the "Query cost (relative to the batch):" for first query it took only 33% and for second with "Top (1) with ties" it took 67%, and if we individually analyze it is an extra sort operator...