# SQL SELECT MAX() is returning multiple records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write a SQL query that brings back record with the MAX ID2 and MAX DATETIME

In my current result,

There are records with the same nmae and special_number. They only differ by ID2 and Date_Time. The special_number should be unique and no duplicates. if there are duplicate special_number, select the record with the max ID2 and date_time

For the duplicates (there are alot of them), I need to only select the record with the MAx ID2 and DATE_TIME. 
For example, ADDEN CROSS, I need to only bring back the ADDEN CROSS with ID2 = 333 and  2017-05-05.

I tried MAX but it did not work

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID, NAME, MAX(ID2), SPECIAL_NUMBER and DATE_TIME
FROm TABLE1
WHERE DATE_TIME BETWEEN @START_DATE and @END_DATE
GROUP BY ID, ID2, SPECIAL_NUMBER, DATE_TIME
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

My Current Results

```
ID      NAME        ID2     SPECIAL_NUMBER  DATE_TIME   
123     JOE SMITH   456     D123            2017-06-05
123     JOE SMITH   455     D123            2017-06-04
124     JIM DONE    111     E111            2017-06-02
122     ME TOO      222     G111            2017-06-01
146     ADDEN CROSS 333     R555            2017-05-05
146     ADDEN CROSS 332     R555            2017-05-04
146     ADDEN CROSS 331     R555            2017-05-02
```

My Expected Results

```
ID      NAME        ID2     SPECIAL_NUMBER  DATE_TIME   
123     JOE SMITH   456     D123            2017-06-05
124     JIM DONE    111     E111            2017-06-02
122     ME TOO      222     G111            2017-06-01
146     ADDEN CROSS 333     R555            2017-05-05
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your results are unique, I suspect you want to get latest ID2 depending o date.

You can make use of `ROW_NUMBER()` in this case.

```
SELECT *
FROM (  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, NAME, SPECIAL_NUMBER, DATE_TIME ORDER BY ID2 DESC) AS RN
          , ID
          , NAME
          , ID2
          , SPECIAL_NUMBER
          , DATE_TIME
        FROM TABLE1
        WHERE DATE_TIME BETWEEN @START_DATE and @END_DATE) AS T
WHERE T.RN = 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use top n with ties as below

```
Select top (1) with ties * from yourtable
    order by row_number() over(partition by name order by Id2 desc)
```

Comment: Never thought of using `WITH TIES` instead of subquery, this is way more elegant!

Comment: But as such sub-query is better performant as top 1 with ties includes one more sort operator... Check my answer in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44310873/filtering-by-rank-in-having-clause-without-subqueries/44311033#44311033

Comment: Yep, I've compared execution plans myself on relatively simple table. Subquery seems to be more efficient being more ugly.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get multiple records is the `GROUP BY` clause.

Consider two rows at the top:

```
ID      NAME        ID2     SPECIAL_NUMBER  DATE_TIME   
123     JOE SMITH   456     D123            2017-06-05
123     JOE SMITH   455     D123            2017-06-04
```

Since `ID`, `ID2`, `SPECIAL_NUMBER`, and `DATE_TIME` are all columns in `GROUP BY`, SQL cannot combine these two records into one that matches your expectation:

```
ID      NAME        ID2     SPECIAL_NUMBER  DATE_TIME   
123     JOE SMITH   456     D123            2017-06-05
```

the value for `ID2` can be 455 or 456; there is no way for SQL to prefer one over the other. Similarly, `DATE_TIME` could be `2017-06-05` or `2017-06-04`, and DB cannot decide which one it should pick without your explicit instructions to select `MAX`.

> I tried `MAX` but it did not work

You were pretty close -- remove `DISTINCT`, and drop `ID2` and `DATE_TIME` from the list:

```
SELECT ID, NAME, MAX(ID2), SPECIAL_NUMBER, MAX(DATE_TIME)
FROM TABLE1
WHERE DATE_TIME BETWEEN @START_DATE and @END_DATE
GROUP BY ID, SPECIAL_NUMBER
```

Comment: This can potentially give incorrect data if `ID2` isn't the record with the highest latest `DATE_TIME`, maybe it is in his data, but there's a chance. :)

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas OP's statement that "I need to only select the record with the MAX `ID2` and `DATE_TIME`" implies that the two become `MAX` on the same record. Otherwise, the choice would be ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

`WITH e AS 
( 
 SELECT *, 
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
     ( 
         PARTITION BY ID, Name, SPECIAL_NUMBER
         ORDER BY ID2 DESC 
     ) AS R 
 FROM TABLE1 
) 
SELECT ID, NAME, ID2, SPECIAL_NUMBER, DATE_TIME 
FROM e 
WHERE DATE_TIME BETWEEN @START_DATE and @END_DATE`